# Cannot remove dynamically added div (with an event triggered by an older div)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, removeclass

I was trying do delete a certain div after an ajax's success action is done. Some code:

Here I try to remove it form the DOM:

```
$('#close-modal').on('click', function () {

    console.log("modal closed");
    $( "#animation" ).remove();

});
```

All this code is inside the `$(document).ready{......}` function

The problem is that, when the form is sent, an animation appears but I cannot remove it by the close of the modal.
I've been investigating and everyone says that it's because the event need to be triggered by .on, but that's in case I need to remove the element by pressing it! And it that case, I need to delete it by doing another action (close the modal).

```
var url = "formulario.php"; // El script a dónde se realizará la petición.
$.ajax(
{
    type: "POST",

    url: url,

    data: $("#formulario").serialize(), // Adjuntar los campos del formulario enviado.

    success: function(data)
    {                       
      $("#formulario_contacto").hide();

      $('.modal-content').append("<div id = "animation" class='icon icon--order-success svg'><svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='72px' height='72px' class = 'posicion'><g fill='none' stroke='#8EC343' stroke-width='2'><circle cx='36' cy='36' r='35' style='stroke-dasharray:240px, 240px; stroke-dashoffset: 480px;'></circle><path d='M17.417,37.778l9.93,9.909l25.444-25.393' style='stroke-dasharray:50px, 50px; stroke-dashoffset: 0px;'></path></g></svg></div>");              
    }
});

event.preventDefault();
```

Hope you can help me. Greetings from Argentina!

Comment: `$( "#animation" ).remove;` should be `$( "#animation" ).remove();`

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in your appending div.
Your error lies in the removal of your appended div here:

```
 $('.modal-content').append("<div id = "animation" class='icon icon--order-success svg'><svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='72px' height='72px' class = 'posicion'><g fill='none' stroke='#8EC343' stroke-width='2'><circle cx='36' cy='36' r='35' style='stroke-dasharray:240px, 240px; stroke-dashoffset: 480px;'></circle><path d='M17.417,37.778l9.93,9.909l25.444-25.393' style='stroke-dasharray:50px, 50px; stroke-dashoffset: 0px;'></path></g></svg></div>");
```

As you may spot when you posted it ... you close dubble quotes of your append when you try to name the id 'animation' here. It wont generated the div with that name then, because this is "out" of the append. You need the double quotes to complete the append... If you do a check on your element, you will see if has no such name.

correct:

```
 $('.modal-content').append("<div id ='animation' class='icon icon--order-success svg'><svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='72px' height='72px' class = 'posicion'><g fill='none' stroke='#8EC343' stroke-width='2'><circle cx='36' cy='36' r='35' style='stroke-dasharray:240px, 240px; stroke-dashoffset: 480px;'></circle><path d='M17.417,37.778l9.93,9.909l25.444-25.393' style='stroke-dasharray:50px, 50px; stroke-dashoffset: 0px;'></path></g></svg></div>");
```

I single quoted it for you.

then call it via your click function as

```
$('#close-modal').on('click', function () {
    $( "#animation" ).remove(); 
});
```

Check if it works now.

Comment: I see, but that's not the problem! I just tipped it wrong when I posted the question. It's correctly written in the original document. But thank you!

Comment: I just checked your link, it didnt struck me as having an error. Did you fix it?

Comment: Send the form and you'll se an animation of a check mark. Close it and it keeps appearing at the bottom of the modal! It is not about an error! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The `remove()` is a function you should add parentheses `()` at the end :

```
$('#close-modal').on('click', function () {
    console.log("modal closed");
    $( "#animation" ).remove();
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah, you're right but that's not the problem! Thanks anyway